# Cumulative Result of Matrix Multiplications

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, matrix-multiplication, array-broadcasting

Given a list of *nxn* matrices, I want to compute the cumulative product of these matrix multiplications - i.e. given matrices M0, M1, ...,Mm I want a result R, where *R[0] = M1, R[1] = M0 x M1, R[2]= M0 x M1 x M2* and so on.

Obviously, you can do this via for-loops or tail recursion, but I'm coding in python, where that runs at a snails pace.

In Code:

```
def matrix_mul_cum_sum(M):
   #M[1..m] is an m x n x n  matrix

   if len(M) == 0:
       return []

   result = [M[1]]
   for A in M[1:]:
       result.append(np.mat_mul(result[-1],A))
   return result
```

For the specific application, n = 4, and m is about 1000 (if that matters). I was hoping to construct a numpy formula for this, but I'm not having much luck. PyTorch is also acceptable, but I don't know it well. Basically, anything faster than the basic for-loop version would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Adding some benchmarks (@hpaulj mentioned that np.linalg.multidot is very slow here, and he is correct).

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
import time
from functools import reduce
n=1000
M = np.random.uniform(0,1,(n,4,4))
attempts = 1000

start = time.time()
for i in range(attempts):
    x1=reduce(np.dot,M)
trd = time.time()-start
trd = np.round(trd/attempts,8)
print('reduce with np.dot: ',trd)


start = time.time()
for i in range(attempts):
    x2=reduce(np.matmul,M)
trm = time.time()-start
trm = np.round(trm/attempts,8)
print('reduce with np.matmul: ',trm)

start = time.time()
for i in range(attempts):
    x3 = M[0]
    for m in M[1:]:
        x3=np.dot(x3,m)
tfd = time.time()-start
tfd = np.round(tfd/attempts,8)
print('for-loop with np.dot:',tfd)

start = time.time()
for i in range(attempts):
    x4 = M[0]
    for m in M[1:]:
        x4=np.matmul(x4,m)
tfm = time.time()-start
tfm = np.round(tfm/attempts,8)
print('for-loop with np.matmul:',tfm)

def tail_rec(x):
    r = x[0]
    helper(x,1,r)
    return r

def helper(x,i,r):
    if i == len(x):
        return
    helper(x,i+1,np.matmul(x[i],r))

start = time.time()
for i in range(attempts):
    x5 = tail_rec(M)
tt = time.time()-start
tt = np.round(tt/attempts,8)
print('tail rec with matmul:',tt)

assert np.allclose(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)

a = np.array([trd,trm,tfd,tfm,tt])
a = np.round(a/a[:,None],3)
print(a)
```

output:

```
reduce with np.dot:  0.00118456
reduce with np.matmul:  0.00126214
for-loop with np.dot: 0.00122364
for-loop with np.matmul: 0.00142755
tail rec with matmul: 0.00194438
[[1.    1.065 1.033 1.205 1.641]
 [0.939 1.    0.969 1.131 1.541]
 [0.968 1.031 1.    1.167 1.589]
 [0.83  0.884 0.857 1.    1.362]
 [0.609 0.649 0.629 0.734 1.   ]]
```

Matrix gives the relative performance of methods. entry i,j is method i's average time divided by method j's average time... smaller numbers in column are better.

It appears that first three methods are all about the same.

Comment: Not every `for loop` is bad.  A few loops on a complex action often are as fast, if not faster than something without the loops but higher memory use.  But in this case I don't think there's anything you can do to avoid successive `matmul`.  Unless math theory suggests some sort of  series formula.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the comment. I did benchmark the for-loop version against np.multidot (which I imagine would have to do the same intermediate computations), and multidot is about 40x faster. I’ll try math stack as well.

Comment: Oops, I see the number of multiplications is relatively large 1000.  Then my comment about a few loops is wrong.  In any case I'm surprised that you find `np.linalg.multi_dot` to be faster.  With your dimensions I find it gets hungup trying to calculate an optimal order (there isn't one).

Comment: @hpaulj you are correct - I was not applying ```np.linalg.multi_dot``` correctly. I edited the question to give a rough idea of time for different methods in case anyone is interested.